# traefik's tls: client didn't provide a certificate when accessing https endpoint

Tags: https, traefik

Here's my configuration

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":801"

  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":802"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]
    [entryPoints.https.tls.ClientCA]
      files = ["/etc/ssl/comodo/bundle.crt"]

      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
        certFile = "/etc/ssl/comodo/www.crt"
        keyFile = "/etc/ssl/comodo/www.key"

[frontends]
    [frontends.http] # default
      entryPoints = ["http", "https"]
      backend = "fallback"
      passHostHeader = true
```

Now I'm trying to access https://mydomain:802 and I get following error in traefik debug output
`http: TLS handshake error from 111.111.111.111:64463: tls: client didn't provide a certificate`

curl error message
`error:14094412:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate`

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to use Mutual authentication (two-way handshake)? For normal SSL connections your server certificates are enough.

In your traefik.toml you're configuring [Mutual authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication). If you really want so, you have to provide the certificate within your curl request:

```
curl --cert client.pem:<password> --key key.pem --cacert ca.pem
```

If you only want to provide "normal" SSL, you should delete following lines:

```
    [entryPoints.https.tls.ClientCA]
      files = ["/etc/ssl/comodo/bundle.crt"]
```